# requests library with googleapiclient

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-api, python-requests, google-api-python-client

Following is the code to access a google storage bucket using the httplib2 library

```
import json
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from pprint import pprint
client_email = 'my.iam.gserviceaccount.com'

json_file = 'services.json'


cloud_storage_bucket = 'my_bucket'

files = 'reviews/reviews_myapp_201603.csv'
private_key = json.loads(open(json_file).read())['private_key']

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, 
private_key,'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only')
storage = build('storage', 'v1', http=credentials.authorize(Http()))
pprint(storage.objects().get(bucket=cloud_storage_bucket, object=files).execute())
```

Can someone tell me if I can make the http request using the Python Requests library here?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can use the HTTP header `Authorization: Bearer <access_token>` with requests or any library you want.

## Service account

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'services.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only'],
)

# Copy access token
bearer_token = credentials.token
```

## User account credentials

```
import json

from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'test.json',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only'
)

# Construct cache path for oauth2 token
oauth2_cache_path = 'test-oauth2.json'

credentials = None

try:
    # Try to load existing oauth2 token
    with open(oauth2_cache_path, 'r') as f:
        credentials = Credentials(**json.load(f))
except (OSError, IOError) as e:
    pass

if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
    credentials = flow.run_console()

    with open(oauth2_cache_path, 'w+') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps({
            'token': credentials.token,
            'refresh_token': credentials.refresh_token,
            'token_uri': credentials.token_uri,
            'client_id': credentials.client_id,
            'client_secret': credentials.client_secret,
            'scopes': credentials.scopes,
        }))

# Copy access token
bearer_token = credentials.token
```

## Use requests lib

```
import requests

# Send request
response = requests.get(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/<endpoint>?access_token=%s'
    % bearer_token)
# OR
response = requests.get(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/<endpoint>',
    headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % bearer_token})
```

## Use googleapiclient lib

I recommend you to use build() method and not requests directly because the google library do some checks before sending your API call (like checking params, endpoint, auth and the method you use). This library also raise exceptions when error is detected.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

storage = build('storage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
print(storage.objects().get(bucket='bucket', object='file_path').execute())
```

More informations here : https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#callinganapi (click on "HTTP/REST" tab)

Comment: Are you able to supply sample code since I am not able to formulate the header. Thank you :)

Comment: @SamyakJain Done :)

Comment: Hello @Calumah,
I used your technique however I am still not able to generate the bearer token.
Is there another way to generate the token?

Comment: @SamyakJain I updated my answer with more informations and fix attribute name to ` credentials.token`

Comment: Hello @Calumah,
thank you so much for the information. Can you also tell me why do you think that the build object is better than the requests library? I mean i understand that google optimized everything with the build function but is there any other reason?

Comment: Also, @Calumah, when you create the json in the code,
the `client_id` is giving me the following error:
'ValueError: Client secrets must be for a web or installed app.'
Is this because i am trying to connect via a service account and I do not have a web/mobile client?

is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @SamyakJain I didn't understand before that you are using an service account, so I added example for that auth method too and explain briefly why  googleapiclient is better than requests lib

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use the official **Google Auth** library which is already implementing **Requests** Library. See [this link](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#making-authenticated-requests) for more information.

Here is a code to try (given that you have a service account file with required permissions):

```py
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession

service_account_file = 'service_account.json'
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control']
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        service_account_file, scopes=scopes)
session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)
bucket_name = 'YOUR-BUCKET-NAME'
response = session.get(f'https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/{bucket_name}')

print(response.json())
```